# When to use SQLalchemy core vs SQLalchemy ORM?

Tags: python, sql

SQLalchemy is two packages in to one; Core & ORM. ORM is built on top of SQLalchemy.

For example, I’m receiving data from an API and I’m inserting it in to a SQL database via SQLalchemy. Should I use Core or ORM?
When is it best to use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly preference, but its possible that SQLAlchemy might (or already did?) deprecate Core at some time in the future. (They are deliberately ambiguous about it I guess)

If you're mostly using raw sql, it seems that SQLAlchemy is simpler and more straight-forward to implement.

If you wanna fiddle around all day with Models, Schemas, Classes, ModelSerializers and abstract everything and never deal with raw query statements again, you should probably go with ORM. But I think its too much busywork, especially if you are proficient at the sql language anyway.

Comment: if you are proficient in SQL would you still use Core? I am writing application and everything is SQL, but there's lot of string interpolation inside queries.

Comment: string interpolation (or string concatenation) is only one good reason to stay away from raw sql, because its vulnerable to one of the most widespread security holes for webapps: SQL-Injection. You gotta dedicate some effort to mitigate it, and having the SQL Alchemy (Core or ORM) Library make queries from Python statements is a good step towards it and does its job to help developers close this security hole. If you are proficient enough to deal with this yourself, you might still find it useful to keep your code pythonic, and SQL Alchemy has some powerful tools to keep your code clean(er)

Comment: Thanks, but I am not concerned with that. It's console app and i am the only user. I choose string interpolation because I can interpolate table names as well as make my own classes to have autocomplete for the column names, unlike SQL alchemy which cannot have autocomplete

Comment: alright, but you can load the database's metadata to get all table names, column names and all their properties automatically if you use SQLAlchemy, which is a huge deal. Personally I just dont think raw sql is pretty. interpolating table names & replacing text just gets messy after even a short while, whereas using SQLAlchemy, you can stay in the programming language you're using in the rest of the program.

Comment: I've tried loading metadata, but I don't think you get autocomplete from that, right? I think only way to get autocomplete is to use ORM with Table classes. I forgot now. I'm fine with raw SQL. I use it to select data and then manipulate in pandas.